# How to Get User Data from Microsoft Teams Bot Just Once

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, azure-bot-service

My web app bot is installed in Teams as an app. (Only in my company(AD) ) Now, I want to fetch users' information such as email, name etc... I don't want to send oauth card again and again to users.

Is there any solution which provides fetching users' (team members') information? Can you please share all setups in Azure AD and Bot framework?

Thanks!

Comment: Please take a look at fetching the [Teams context from your Bot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/get-teams-context?tabs=dotnet).

Comment: Uh oh, thank you so much! How can I keep user's information? Eg. In one dialog, I need user's mail address, where can I fetch this?

Comment: You can fetch the email address from the context, Could you please try the code specified in my previous comment?